# .NET 7 Web API Identity - can't login via hashed password

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have created a custom hash method which returns a hash string then use this as the `HashPassword` field for the `ApplicationUser`.

Attempting to login via the `SignInManager` results in failure regardless of hashing the password and it matching the database entry's hashed password.

I've also attempted sending the regular password in case Identity automatically hashes and creates salt. I'm new to hashing/cryptography as well as Identity and am a bit lost as to how I can get logins working.

Login controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/account/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        string hashedPass = PasswordHasher(password);
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, hashedPass, true, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
            return Ok(result);
        else
           return BadRequest(result);
    }
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using SdeResearch.Api.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SdeResearchDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SdeResearchDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password Settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit= true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric= true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength= 8;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

    // User settings
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+!";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail= true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Topic",
    pattern: "topic/*{action}"
    );

app.Run();
```

`DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SdeResearch.Api.Models
{
    public class SdeResearchDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Researcher> Researchers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResearcherArticle> ResearcherArticles { get; set; }

        public SdeResearchDbContext(DbContextOptions<SdeResearchDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString");
        }
    }
}
```

If there is any other information I can provide which would help, please let me know.

Comment: Could you show how you injected  _signInManager?

Comment: I have decided to return to the default password hash method.

Comment: I just want to check the signinanager is type of SigninManager<AppUser> or SigininManager<IdentityUser>

Comment: It is SignInManager<ApplicationUser> rather than the default SignInManager<IdentityUser>